# $timeout for $http with specific URL AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, timeout

Here is my code : 
JS:

```
var timer;
$scope.getapi_url = function(n){
       var url = n;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
                console.log($scope,data);
                timer = $timeout($scope.getapi_url(), 5000);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorBackend = true;
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-clear btn-sm" ng-click="getapi_url('myurl') ">Click!</button>
```

After the first `$timeout` I am getting an error thrown, something like `n is undefinded`

What can I do with that?

Thanks in advance for all the answers!!!

Comment: are you mixing `vm` with `$scope` by any chance? Does your HTML code have _controllerAs_ syntax?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah, actually i have var vm = this; and it mixing with $scope - can be that a problem?

Comment: I'm just confused why you have both `$scope.getapi_url` and `vm.getapi_url`

Comment: Oh this is my misteake with writing this answer

Comment: in my code i have only vm

Comment: why you want recursion in API call and what is the exit for statement for recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but It'll never stop, you have to stop manually using `$timeout.cancel(timer);`.

```
var timer;
$scope.getapi_url = function (n) {
    var url = n;
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.data = data.data;
            console.log($scope, data);
            timer = $timeout($scope.getapi_url(n), 5000); 
            // passing n if you don't want check n value on starting of function.
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.errorBackend = true;
            console.log(response);
            console.log('error');
        });
};
```

Comment: @bafix2203 you can write condition before calling $http. if(n) then call API else to skip.